# how do I optimize my java code?

Tags: java, file, sorting

I'm new to JAVA. I've been through some tutorials and I'm in the next step of checking how I'm doing now. 
Please feel free to criticize the code block below. Any feedback is appreciated. Thanks!

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Vector;

import org.apache.log4j.helpers.FileWatchdog;


/**
* 
* Simple class that reads in a file - sorts its lines in natural order,  
* writes it back out to the given filename and adds a timestamp of when it was sorted
* 
* Program will be called with:
* 
* java TestClass <input_filename> <output_filename>
*
*/

public class TestClass {


public static void main(String [] args) throws RuntimeException{
    boolean OVERWRITE_FILE = true;
    //get filename from args
    String inputFilename = args[0];
    String outputFilename = args[1];

    //check usage
    if(args.length != 2){
        System.out.println("Incorrect number of args");
        System.out.println("Correct usage is:");
        System.out.println(" java TestClass <input_filename> <output_filename> ");
        System.exit(-1);
    }

    //read in file into collection
    try {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFilename));
        Vector fileContents = new Vector<Object>();
        while(in.ready()){
            fileContents.add(in.readLine());
        }

        //sort the collection in natural order
        Collections.sort(fileContents);

        //add timestamp
        fileContents.add("File Sorted on: ");
        fileContents.add(new Date());

        //write outputFile
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(outputFilename, OVERWRITE_FILE));
        for(int i = 0; i < fileContents.size(); i++){
            out.write((String)fileContents.get(i) + "\n");
        }
        //close output file
        out.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error while performing IO");
    }

}
}
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Better fit for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The `Vector` class is not recommended to be used anymore. Use one of the `List` sub-classes instead. The contents of the vector are `String` objects, so you should create a vector of strings instead of `Object`.

Comment: Your question would be *very* welcome on [codeReview.se].

Comment: If you use Java 7, the reading part can be done in one line with `List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(file, charset);` and the writing part with `Files.write(file, lines, charset)`.